# Functional testing and continuous integration with GitLab

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I usually use GitLab to host my repositories and to use their CI/CD.
I made a Symfony project (PHP) with some code. I know how to configure my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to execute my unit tests through PHPUnit.

But I don't really understand how to execute my functional test. For example this code is just testing that the route `/login` is reachable and not return a 500.

```
class SecurityControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/login');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

So I assume that apache/nginx is needed to interpret PHP. So do I have to make a real docker-compose with a complete LAMP stack or is there a better way?

Comment: I could have a nightmares if I haven't clarify a thing: That test asserts "status is 200", not "status is not 500".

Comment: Have you actually tried running the above on CI? These tests are not run against a webserver, but a symfony kernel is booted up and the code is executed against that.

Comment: When you run this test on your local computer. does your test use Apache/Nginx to assert? can you shutdown your web server and run the test? cause I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Functional tests are executed directly in phpunit. You only need to install browser-kit and dom-crawler symfony components.

If you use an ORM, you have to declare a database image as a service and initialize your database in your CI script.

Comment: You are right but this is part of my question. When I run all my test (unit and functionnal) on my local computer, it works. But if I want to run my test on GitHub/GitLab/... I have to reproduce a LAMP stack, my question is, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to reproduce a full LAMP stack for executing functional tests. Or you want to execute E2E tests?